# Where is "remote tracking branch" in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How to find "remote tracking branch" in TortoiseGit to set default branch to pull from?

[image: Description image]

Comment: I dont know but in case of doubt, open and use the console. (git bash if you are on windows)

Comment: I pull changes through right click on project folder (where git installed) and chose Remote Branch every time. I want to put another remote branch by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the "Browse Refs" dialog (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-browse-ref.html). There you can see all local branches and the corresponding remote-tracking branches (you can change the remote-tracking branch using the context menu).

[image: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/images/BrowseRef.png]

On the pull and fetch dialog, the currently set remote tracked branch should be selected automatically (based on the current local branch) - or the last used remote branch is preselected.

PS: In order to automatically set it up on push, just enable "Set upstream/track remote branch" on the push dialog.

PSS: On the push dialog, there are some TGit specific options, that allow you to have an remote tracked branch (e.g., master from upstream), but store another default where you push to (e.g., master from origin; cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html).