# TortoiseGit pulling from all branches not considering remote branch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am not able to make tortoisegit (win 10) to pull **ONLY** my remote branch info. It always pull all the remote branch info taking 5-10 mins.

What I tried from tortoise git
[image]

Internally tortoise executes

```
  git.exe pull --progress -v --no-rebase --depth 1 "origin"
```

rather than below leading to downloading everything info

```
 git pull --progress -v --no-rebase --depth 1 "origin" "kamet_556_108_py377"
```

I set the tracking branch to point to kamet_556_108_py377 ( [Where is "remote tracking branch" in TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516580/where-is-remote-tracking-branch-in-tortoisegit) )

**From Git bash console:**

```
$  git checkout  -f --recurse-submodule -B kamet_556_108_py377 origin/kamet_556_108_py377
Reset branch 'kamet_556_108_py377'
Branch 'kamet_556_108_py377' set up to track remote branch 'kamet_556_108_py377' from 'origin'.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/kamet_556_108_py377'.
```

Can anyone point me what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you checked the history of your local kamet_556_108_py377 branch? It looks like it should be up to date with the remote branch.

Comment: @Malice: Sorry for late response. I ran `git diff kamet_556_108_py377...origin/kamet_556_108_py377` no difference.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question but Git is reporting that your local branch is up to date with the remote branch and the diff command is showing no differences so what else do you need TortoiseGit to do?

Comment: @Malice: Corect me. if I am wrong. `git.exe pull --progress -v --no-rebase --depth 1 "origin"` will download info for all the local branches. If so, if want only for specific branch, I need to specify remote branch in the git pull command. correct ? Tortoise Git is not adding my remote branch when firing query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not want to download all the remote info info every time when do TortoiseGit->Pull. Similar issue was reported by another user 4 yrs back [https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/202]

As per that, **I disabled tracking by remote branch** as below and now I am able to pull only info regarding my private branch `kamet_556_108_py377` under few secs (from  mins)

[image]

[image]